# What are your favorite open source or free library for .NET Charts and Gauges?

Tags: .net, charts, open-source

For a in-house hardware monitoring utility, I need to use gauges and charts to help visualize various metrics. Is there any good open source or free charting and gauge library available for .NET? I am not interested in purchasing any components (which excludes components such as Dundas Charts & Graph, which I know would do the job, but would not fit in our budget).

**Edit:** I also know about Google Charts API. The actual application needs to work without an internet connection, so it is out of the question in this particular case.

Comment: I've got a similar need (asp.net, intranet-only environment).. what did you end up using?

Comment: Check out Nevron Chart Community Edition - it is free:
https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-chart-free-control.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this isn't open source, but it's worth noting that Microsoft just released a free charting pack for ASP.NET and WinForms. More details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2008/10/25/microsoft-chart-controls-for-net-framework-35.aspx).

Comment: It was pretty much what I was looking for, minus the gauges... Thanks!

Comment: Just started using this (literally tonight).  It was actually pretty easy to get my first chart up and running.

Comment: From what I've read I believe this cannot be shipped just as a dll - you need to install the microsoft charts exe on the client pc. So if your using clickonce like me that means building your own bootstrapper.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite one is [ZedGraph.](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Definitely a fantastic charting library.

Comment: It's good for diagram and plots but gauges?

Comment: I've only used it for plots and diagrams.  I've used it for interactive timelines and such but not gauges.

Comment: Did they get any better than 3 years ago? I remember that 3 years ago... this package was kind of "Beta-ish"

Comment: It's pretty solid - at least for my needs.

Comment: link was broken but this looks like it: http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html

Answer (score 1):

The two I happen to have in my del.icio.us account:

Are [FLOT](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for jQuery.

And this posting at Code Project for [Gantt Charts](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Gantt_Chart.aspx)

Comment: +1 for Flot. It's as dynamic as a Flash chart, but only requires JS. Works fine in IE6 and iPhones as well.

Answer (score 1):

ZedGraph definitely.

I use charts for large data-sets, 1,000,000 data points and upwards.
ZedGraph is succinct, performant and succeeds in rendering these beast-like-graphs
much faster than lots of commercial products I've tried like:
Nevron
SyncFusion
DevExpress
ChartFX
Dundas (hence also Microsoft Charts)

ZedGraph has some specific high performance features that are un-paralleled like [FilterPointList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_FilteredPointList.htm) which dynamically snap-shots your data when you are zoomed out, and doesn't use snapshots when you are zoomed in.

Comment: Does it support editing the data directly in the chart out of the box? I don't need a million data points, but would like to let users define depreciation by dragging data points on a spline chart (rather than enter the series in tabular format into a datagridview). So the chart would both show and be used to define value vs time. For some reason it appears few think about what charts can do as *input* controls, but anyone who ever used photoshop knows they're fantastic (stretch histograms, adjust color curves, ...)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/A_Gauge.aspx?msg=1900283

Comment: because gauge is not there in Zed graph

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a look at NPlot, but it looks a bit impenetrable at first glance.